# Meteor packages that are not compatible with meteor 0.9.x

Tags: meteor, package

What are the disadvantages of using Meteor packages that are not compatible with Meteor.js 0.9.x when I am developing applications with Meteor.js 0.9.x?

Comment: Most of them will crash your app at the build step, so you won't even start your app in development mode.

Comment: Also, most of those packages already have a compatible counterpart with a different prefix.